# Bootstrap Confidence Interval for Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, prediction, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to calculate a confidence interval for the RMSE of a machine learning regression in the out-of-sample test set predictions.

My train set is the first 80% of the sample, and the "out-of-sample" test set is the last 20% of the sample. I treat the RMSE of the test set predictions as the out-of-sample performance, and would like to calculate a CI of this RMSE.

One idea I had was to resample the train set among the first 80%, but use the same test set each iteration. This would seem to represent the CI of RMSE on the test set across different possible training scenarios. However, it would not account for possible variation in the test set.

Is this approach sensible? Is there a better way to address my question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to fix the test set to be that exact sample of observations?

One approach would be to repeatedly split the dataset into training and test sets at the 80-20 proportion you are currently using. After each random (with replacement) split, proceed as usual. That is, train your model, then calculate the RMSE on the test data. You can perform, say, 10,000 bootstraps of this form, save the associated RMSE values, and calculate the confidence interval of these values.

See, e.g., Chapter 5 of [Hastie et al](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461471370).

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the test set must come strictly after the train set (i.e. the first 10 years used for train, the last 2 years used for test) to simulate realistic prediction using the model. If the test set drew from the same years as the train set, there is the possibility of overfitting to those years, and the test set would not function as a genuine out-of-sample simulation. Do you have any suggestion for how to use your resampling method under this constraint?